# AnnounceForAccessibility with ExplorationByTouch turn off

Tags: android, view, accessibility, talkback

I keep trying to make my custom input method for blind people more accessible.
I had a problem AnnounceForAccessibility() doesn't work with ExplorationByTouch turn off (TalkBack is turn on). How can I resolve this problem?
Can I turn off ExplorationByTouch only for my View?

Comment: `View.announceForAccessibility()` only checks whether accessibility is turned on. It should still work fine even with Explore by Touch disabled. Are you seeing that it *only* works when EBT is on, or it *never* works?

Comment: It only works when EBT is on.